# .NET Create an array with unknown size until runtime (or a better way of array slicing)

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I have a block of several lines of text. I've split this like so:

```
var lines = mytext.Split(new string[] {Environment.NewLine}, 
                         StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Now, I need to get a subset of the lines - namely a remainder. In Python I would do something like this:

```
>>> lines = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
>>> lines[3:]
['three', 'four']
```

But this is obviously not legal syntax in .NET.

So I found the [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, and figured, a hah! I'll just do this:

```
var newlines = new string[lines.Length-someAmount]{};
```

to get me a list I can copy into.

but then I got an error saying that I can't make an array like that - the number has to be known at compile time! Okay, well, I'll try [something else](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw8e0z9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - silly, but it should work, right?

```
var newlinesList = new List<string>(lines.Length-someAmount);
var newlines = newlinesList.ToArray();
```

Then I can use:

```
Array.Copy(lines, startIndex, bodylines, 0, lines.Length-startIndex);
```

Except for one problem - apparently `ToArray()` filters out the empty/null values, so I can't actually copy it.

So how do I create an array with the size unknown until runtime, or even better, how can I simply slice an array?

Comment: `the size unknown until runtime` -> that means you don't need an array although we can resize an array, why not just use `List<>`?

Comment: May I ask why you chose not to use a `List<T>`?

Comment: `new List<T>(int)` sets the _capacity_ of an empty list.

Comment: `Python` is very powerful in dealing with array stuff (and the like), I don't think you can find some easy way to have all the corresponding versions in c#, although we can write such a library.

Comment: @KingKing, because the authors of `Array.Copy` decided to require the destination array of some size. Don't ask me why...

Comment: "ToArray() filters out the empty/null values"??? Do you have sample? (`(new List<string>{"test", null, null}).ToArray()` works perfectly)

Comment: @WayneWerner I just feel there is something too broad in your question, you don't even need to post some python code, just try digging into a specific problem and it would be solved completely.

Comment: @KingKing, Probably a valid point. I'm thinking that the *capacity* part confused me - I was expecting that it set the initial size. Probably a holdover from C++ vectors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways. Perhaps the easiest is with LINQ:

```
var newArray = lines.Skip(3).ToArray();
```

And if you wanted to take just two items (assuming the `lines` array had more than 5), you'd write:

```
var newArray = lines.Skip(3).Take(2).ToArray();
```

Or, if you only wanted the first three:

```
var newArray = lines.Take(3).ToArray();
```

Which, I think, pretty much covers array slicing.

Answer (score 5):

You absolutely can do that – just don't pass a list of elements:

```
var newlines = new string[lines.Length-someAmount];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int cursor = 3; //Number of element to start copying from
string[] newlines  = new string[lines.Length - cursor];
Array.Copy(lines, cursor, newlines, 0, lines.Length - cursor);
```